# Programmatically extracting R binary package contents and moving them to library folder?

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-package

**Using R version 3.6.2, RStudio version 1.2.5033, Windows 10**

I am compiling a report in Rmarkdown, and am finished except for some troubleshooting with the packages, specifically, those that need compilation and are delivered as binary format into a temp folder outside my working directory.

I am able to extract and copy these binary package contents individually to my library folder on my machine, but generally assume those reading the report will not have all the packages already installed.

Normally I handle packages requirements as follows:

```
# Install from github if not present
if (!require(devtools)) {
  install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
}

# Install from CRAN if not present
if (!require(installr)) {
  install.packages("installr", dependencies = TRUE)
}

# Now we can use abbreviated require2 function for remainder
installr::require2(stringi, ask = FALSE, dependencies = TRUE)
.
.
.
```

What I am having trouble with is that 'stringi' package wants compilation upon running command for a machine without this package, and if I select 'no,' then it downloads as binary to a temporary folder.  I then need to extract this manually outside of RStudio, which I don't want others to have to do.

So, *is there a way to automate this process?  Is there a better approach to what my aim is here that removes the issue altogether?*

Thank you in advance for your insights and your patience (this is my first question).